# CSS Layout Breaks upon Zooming in / out

Tags: css

I am a self-taught web designer with a staggering 3 sites or so under my belt. I just finished the first page of a website for a client who is a friend and therefore a lot more patient than a "real" client would be.

I love the way the sites looks, it is fairly consistent in the spectrum of popular browsers, and overall I was quite proud of it until I realize a major problem that to be honest is about two steps away from making me drop my dream of becoming a web designer.

When using Chrome, Safari, or older versions of Explorer the website's layout falls apart if someone has their zoom set to anything other than 100%.

It is frustrating me to the point of near depression. I used a div to surround the whole body, and the pages layout, which in this case is a MENU is done almost entirely with ULs (unordered lists) positioned absolutely.

The site is made up in such a way that all the parts connect (almost like a puzzle) and if some parts are out of line, it is dreadfully obvious.

I heard the zooming rounds up figures and could call for a couple of low alpha pixels here and there, but in my case some block elements are literally 25-50 pixels out of place.

http://www.stevemarcella.com

Comment: Looks like tablephobia here.  Most of that content is tabular data, but has been shoehorned into lists (a list of what shouldn't be put into a table would actually be shorter than a list of what should be in a table).  Also, you should look into Responsive Design.

Answer (score 1):

No need to get your dreams crushed just yet :> There is always hope.

First thing you should do is check all of the errors, which according to validator are 536 errors on the homepage.
I suggest you run the validator and correct errors one by one. It could solve your problems. First error I noticed is that you have a div element outside of body. You should keep everything inside the body tags.

This is outside of body.

```
<div class="wrapAroundBody" id="IdWrappingWholeBody">
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Interesting points Cimmanon, because I do have this bias against using tables. And will look into responsive design.

Thanks for pointing out the wraping div outside the body, and can you please elaborate on what this validator tool is? I am interested

Thanks again

Comment: You can validate your site here: http://validator.w3.org/ or you can use something like this [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) which has validator tool and much more useful stuff for web development.